# Find Time Difference

Tags: java, time

I want to find time difference in java so that I can create new session if session expires else will assign new time.

Comment: Don't you mean this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027100/best-way-to-calculate-differnce-between-two-times-in-java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Returns Time Diffrence in Seconds :




long elapsed_time = 0L;
    java.util.Date startTime = null;
    java.util.Date endTime = null;
    double fsec = 0L;
    String rSec = "";   

        startTime = new java.util.Date();

        <--------Some Operation----->

        endTime = new java.util.Date();
        elapsed_time = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
        fsec = (elapsed_time) / 1000.00;
        rSec = Double.toString(fsec);
        rSec = rSec + " Sec";
```

Comment: +0: Using Date is relatively heavy weight and often inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis();` to get the current system time in Java (in milliseconds since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 GMT).

The session object most likely also has a method to get the time when the session was last used (look it up in the API documentation of whatever session object you're using).

Subtract the current time from that time from the session and you know how long it has been since the session was last used. If it is longer than the timeout period, do whatever you have to do.

Note that servlet containers have a built-in mechanism for invalidating sessions, you don't need to invalidate sessions manually. Also, `HttpRequest.getSession()` will automatically create a new `HttpSession` object for you if there is no session.

Answer (score 2):

Using Date means creating an object which isn't need as it just wraps `System.currentTimeMillis()` Unfortunately this function is only accurate to a milli-second at best and about 16 ms on some windows systems.

A better approach is to use `System.nanoTime()` On Oracle's JVM, on Windows XP - 7, Solaris and on recent versions of Linux, this is accurate to better than 1 micro-second. It doesn't create any objects.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// do something.
long time = System.nanoTime() - start; // time in nano-seconds.
// time in seconds to three decimal places
String timeTaken = time/1000000/1e3 + " seconds";
```

Comment: There is actually no guarantee to how accurate `nanoTime()` is; the Java API does not guarantee that it is accurate to less than 1 microsecond. But this is a better solution than using a `java.util.Date` object.

Comment: @Jesper, I agree there is no guarentee. However Oracle's JVM happens to do this on Windows XP - 7, Solaris and on recent versions of Linux.

Comment: true, but maybe you should mention that instead of stating without caveat that it's accurate to less than 1 microsecond.

Comment: +1: but on my XP it is accurate to NOT less than 1.4 μs [:-)  (writed before I have seen the update)