# Android Compare epoch time and today date and output the difference

Tags: java, android, date, time, epoch

I need to calculate a expiry date difference.

I will get this epoch time:

> 1481410800  (06-Dec-2016 (14:42))

now I want to calculate the days until the expiry date (1481410800)

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy (HH:mm)", Locale.getDefault());


//Expiry Date
        long unixSecondsExpiry = 1481410800; //unixSeconds
        Date expiryDate = new Date(unixSecondsExpiry*1000L);



        long currentDate = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        long diff = unixSecondsExpiry - currentDate;
        long days = diff / (24l * 60l * 60l * 1000l);




        String formattedExpiryDate = sdf.format(expiryDate);
        String formattedDateNow = sdf.format(new Date());

        Log.w("RUNTEST", "formattedDateNow: " + formattedDateNow);
        Log.w("RUNTEST", "formattedExpiryDate: " + formattedExpiryDate);
        Log.w("RUNTEST", "days: " + days);
```

I keep getting 17 days but it should be 5 days till expiry.

> RUNTEST: formattedDateNow: 06-Dec-2016 (14:42)
>
> RUNTEST: formattedExpiryDate: 11-Dec-2016 (07:00)
>
> RUNTEST: days: 17

Comment: Also a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6218928. Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using `new Date()`

```
String formattedDateNow = sdf.format(new Date());
```

but the calculation is using

```
long currentDate = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Why not just use

```
long currentDate = new Date().getTime ();
```

**edit**

`get`ting the SECONDS from a calendar is just getting the current seconds counter

> Field number for get and set indicating the second within the minute.
>   E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the SECOND is 15.